# Google chrome version that keeps open on bar

Tags: google-chrome, google

I was using the latest chrome version for ubuntu 16.04 that always kept open like a bar icon next to the wifi and I know it ate  more ram but it was faster. After I reinstalled ubuntu in my laptop I have updated everything and I have the latest version of chrome the "Version 53.0.2785.143 (64-bit)" but I is not  the one that kept open on the bar. Someone knows which version is that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The version is not important because this feature has been in Chrome for a long time. Here's how to have Chrome run in the system tray:

1. Open the settings in Chrome
2. Scroll to the bottom and click "Advanced options"
3. Check the box next to "Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed."

Answer (score 0):

You can check for Chrome version with `apt-show`

First you list all packages with "chrome" in the name:

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep chrome
```

Then use `apt-show` to check its version, something like this:

```
apt-show chrome | grep Version
```

Comment: used apt-cache, got this result:

Comment: google-chrome-stable:
  Installed: 54.0.2840.59-1
  Candidate: 54.0.2840.59-1
  Version table:
 *** 54.0.2840.59-1 500
        500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: may I see screenshot of that chrome on its location that you mentioned?

Comment: here's the version

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwBdc.png

Comment: Checking version is easier with this command: `google-chrome --version`

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using Chromium right now, not Google Chrome. If the symbol in the launcher is blue (different shades of blue), you're using Chromium. If the symbol only has a blue circle in the middle but is red, yellow, and green on the outside, you're using Google Chrome.

Chromium doesn't put a symbol into the system bar, Google Chrome does.

Note that you can install Chromium from the repositories via:

```
sudo apt install chromium-browser
```

Google Chrome, on the other hand, must be downloaded from [here](https://www.google.com/chrome/) and then be installed for example via

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/google-chrome*.deb
```

Comment: I did, actually reinstalled again for uefi compatibility and I have the 54 version that went out yesterday. Still not getting the icon

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with UEFI. Is the symbol in the launcher pied?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by pied? Its the chrome symbol yellow green and red. Nothing related, just saying that I reinstalled ubuntu again for other reason, reinstalled chrome to new version from the google chrome page ad a .deb and still getting the without the icon next to the wifi. For the record this is the version that I have: google-chrome-stable: Installed: 54.0.2840.59-1 Candidate: 54.0.2840.59-1 Version table: *** 54.0.2840.59-1 500 500 dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status –